# Remove a specific word from a Filereader

Tags: java, filereader, filewriter

I have this code, my goal is to remove the words "the". So the output will look like this.

> Blockquote
>   water is wet. man is angry. bed is warm.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what to do, I've tried using replaceALL but it doesn't work. The output will then be written in a textfile. Any help would do.

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.FileWriter;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.*;

public class FR{
    public static void main (String[]args) throws IOException {


File THE = new File("a.txt");
    String replace;
    THE.createNewFile();
    FileWriter writer = new FileWriter(THE);
    writer.write("The water is wet.\n");
    writer.write("The man is angry.\n");
    writer.write("The bed is warm.");
    writer.flush();
    writer.close();

    FileReader READ = new FileReader(THE);
    char [] x = new char [70];
    READ.read(x);
        System.out.print(x);
    READ.close();
    }
}
```

Comment: Im just new here in stackoverflow, my first time asking a question

Comment: Can you share the snippet where you tried using `replaceAll`?

Answer (score 2):

The problem is x is not a String, is a char [], so you have to convert it to String first

```
FileReader READ = new FileReader(THE);
char [] x = new char [70];
READ.read(x);
String xAsString = String.valueOf(x).replace("The ", "");
System.out.print(xAsString);
READ.close();
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help